# Excel VBA Essbase ZoomIn

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, essbase

I am using the `EssVZoomIn` Function to zoom in on a dataset in Essbase.

The function works in the sense that it zooms in, but it also removes the account dimension row out of the dataset when I run the code.

So [image]

When I zoom in manually on the same exact data, it does not remove the account dimension. Also, if I zoom-in manually, then zoom in through the code it does not remove the dimension either.

I feel like it has to do with some type of setting, but after resourcing with some colleagues and the web, I am still at a loss.

Here's my Zoom in Code

```
    With ws_zoom 
        EssVZoomIn .Name, .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("E7").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)), _
 .Range(.Range("A7"), .Range("A7").End(xlDown).Offset(, 3)), 3, False 
    End With
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in columns F and beyond? In other words, have you tried this with the 'normal' look with your POV members going across the columns instead of the stacked format you have right now?

I'm just wondering if you're bumping in to some quirk with how the grid processor works. Essbase is *pretty lenient* when it comes to interpreting how the rows/columns are laid out but it can definitely take some liberties with relaying things out.

Comment: jwj, this is the normal look. i do have more time periods going across column F in my real example. however, the point is that the zoom works and get the right data out, however, it completely deletes the account row from the spreadsheet, which doesn't help when people want to be sure of exactly what the retrieve is

Comment: Okay. I guess what I was getting at was if you had tried slightly different POV layouts to see if you still get the issue... with the goal being to try and figure out if it's just a VB API bug or something in the "non-common" grid layout that may be throwing things off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "Repeat Member Labels" option to ensure that it isn't just pushing the label out to the center column in the output?  From the help file on Repeate Member Labels: By default, Essbase displays member labels only once for each set of data... (meaning: entries common to a group of adjacent columns will appear once in the center of the group).  Turning the option on will cause Essbase to fill in each column header regardless of duplicated values in adjacent columns.

I would also recommend that if you have any attribute dimensions listed that they be at the bottom/right of their base dimension items.  The issue is not likely to create problems as described, but could lead to zoom-in confusion depending on the sequence.

If the first paragraph doesn't address your issue (I suspect it will), it might help to show a layout that replaces each of the members displayed with the dimension they come from (A1:E8 in your worksheet image above).  This "formatting view" can then be used to help identify what exactly the zoomin is doing - especially if you color code the dense/sparse and base/attribute dims differently.

If ASO, much of the above doesn't apply, ofc.